# Why do prisoners want to live in Emerald City?

Tags: oz

In Oz, many prisoners have to change their location from the experimental unit Emerald City and some normal units, and vice versa.

Emerald City is extremely controlled with much more prison officers, and it seems that the living environment is worse than in normal units (There are harly any private things; plus when he was in a normal unit, Schillinger was seen with a personal radio device, playing at a pool table, etc.). Also, there seems to be much more violence within Emerald City than in the rest of the prison.

If I were a prisoner, I would definitly not want to live in 
Emerald City.

However, a lot of prisoners are even begging for being there, or complaining if they have to leave (e.g., when Martin Querns, the replacement of McManus, began to reorganize Emerald City and exchanged a lot of prisoners. But also during the whole series). **Why? What is so attractive for prisoners that they want to live in Emerald City rather than in any other prison unit?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [OZTV wiki](http://oztv.wikia.com/wiki/Emerald_City); Emerald City (Em City) was a substantially more pleasant living environment than the main prison which was riven with inter-gang violence and overcrowding:

> The unit, unlike other units, offers rehabilitation programs to the
>   prisoners. The prisoners are allowed to walk around and talk to the
>   prisoners in the unit and they are allowed to play card games and
>   board games, all in their own clothes (not like other units that
>   demand prison uniforms).

The unit also offers unlimited TV privileges, a laundry room, a computer room, unlimited phone privileges and dedicated educational rooms.